# Create a 3D Bar Chart in AS3 and HTML5

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, html, charts

I have to create a 3D Bar chart in Flash(AS3) and HTML5 which takes up input from a source and generates the graph, and they both should look alike, so what options do i have?? i mean are there any open libraries which will assist me to do it? (it should be Open Source)

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: to add to it, it can be either Bar or Column or even Pie Chart in 3D

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you would maybe want to start with something like Haxe to have a common framework that compiles to multiple languages.  I'm not aware of any charting libraries that use Haxe (or are built using Haxe rather), or that are written to have a parallel between AS3 and HTML/JS.  Instead of having to use something like Haxe or writing multiple versions in different languages and having to keep them up to date you could have a server side java handle generating the chart (returning bitmap data), the only issue with this is if you want interaction on the chart which puts you sort of in the same boat again.

Another option is to roll your own I did something like a "3d" bar chart while out camping one weekend (took two full charges of my laptop battery, but got it done without the internet).

http://www.shaunhusain.com/charts/

http://www.shaunhusain.com/charts/srcview/

I actually put it in that charts folder with the intention of circling back around to clean this up and do Pie/Line ones with similar 3d effect (not actually using any 3d).

There's some decent tutorials on writing your own charts, so long as they don't get too crazy with the design you could probably DIY.  Plus whichever language you're weaker with you can just port to every time, so you start strong then learn how to convert.

**EDIT**
The ads are getting smarter than the people (this was on the right of this page when I loaded it): http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=banner&utm_content=1_billion_banner_karate_220x250_px_white_fo&utm_campaign=FC_v3_2_Mktg

Comment: Hi shaunhusain, thanks for taking time in replying, here are my comments,
haxe is not suitable as this is used inside an app which can publish to html or swf and when selected i have to generate that output, and that app is already built, also, no server side scripting, it should run locally even without internet,
and for the Links you gave, thanks i probably have to do that only, write my own.. that might come in handy :)
And for the edit, i'm aware of Fusion Charts, but it is not open source :) thanks anyway :)